# Gnome: detect copy-on-select

Tags: linux, clipboard

On CentOS 7.6 I've noticed that when text in a text field is selected it can easily by pasted using middle-click somewhere else - independent of the normal Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V-clipboard. On other Linux systems, e.g. Ubuntu 18.04, this does not work.

How can I find out from our Java application whether this feature is available?
Usually, tabbing through a GUI with multiple text fields this selects the text, but both features collide somehow, so I just want to enable the select-all-on-tab feature in our application if there is no copy-on-select feature enabled for the system.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking if you are running a X server and not Wayland or X over Wayland.

If you have an actual X server, then the PRIMARY selection buffer exists and the copying by selection and pasting by middle clicking will work. If you aren't running under an X server, such functionality might not exist.

The CLIPBOARD buffer holds the clipboard that isn't changed by selection.

Comment: By checking `XDG_SESSION_TYPE` for `x11` or `wayland`?